# How do I make Google default English in Chrome?

Tags: google-search, google-account, google-chrome, localization

If I go to Search Settings / Languages / select English / Save, it goes to English but then keeps switching to Slovak.

In my Cookies, I have 'Allow local data to be set' checked.

I'm in Ireland and I'd like local search results in English.

But Google gives me search results from Slovakia and the Czech Republic, and Google is in Slovak.

The same happens whether or not I am signed into my Google account, so I guess there's a file somewhere on my computer telling Chrome to give me search results in Slovak and from Slovakia.

How do I make Google default English in Chrome?

..

Edit:

This page has some answers:

http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=533

But none of those things resolve this.

Comment: What's your operating system? (reply to this comment plz)

Comment: This one helped me: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/K3CDmDWGsBc/Uk5W-zK9eVAJ

Answer (score 3):

Visit http://google.com/ncr in your browser. The NCR stands for "No Country Redirect" and it will tell Google not to use any kind of country-specific behaviour.

Comment: http://www.google.com/ncr redirects me to http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=f62JVoLCHozl-gbN4aLgBQ